# How do I write a use statement in order to import a name but use it as mod1::mod2::item?

Tags: module, rust

Given that the file `src/A/B/C.rs` exists, what `use` statement would I write in a file `src/D.rs` so that I can access `C` as `A::B::C`?

I've tried: `use A::B::C`, but then I cannnot refer to it as `A::B::C`.  I've tried: `use A::{B::C}`, but then I can only refer to it as `B::C`.

Comment: By the way, idiomatic Rust uses `snake_case` for variables, methods, macros, fields and modules; `UpperCamelCase` for types and enum variants; and `SCREAMING_SNAKE_CASE` for statics and constants.

Comment: It's hard to answer your question because it doesn't include a [MRE]. We can't tell what modules, how you've included them, etc. in the code. It would make it easier for us to help you if you try to reproduce your error on the [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org) if possible, otherwise in a brand new Cargo project, then [edit] your question to include the additional info. There are [Rust-specific MRE tips](//stackoverflow.com/tags/rust/info) you can use to reduce your original code for posting here. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```rust
mod A;

fn main() {
    A::B::C::ModuleCfn();
}
```

Here are the files and modules that i tried:

```
src/A.rs =>
    pub mod B;
src/A/B.rs =>
    pub mod C;
src/A/B/C.rs =>
    pub fn ModuleCfn() { }
```

Comment: This works for `main.rs` or `lib.rs`, but if the `mod` statement is in `lib.rs` and you want to refer to `A::B::C` from another top level module, you'll need a `use A;` (or is it `use crate::A;`? I can't remember, any more...)

Comment: Hi trentcl, I tried "use A;" and it worked!  Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose I want to refer to:

`actix_web_httpauth::extractors::bearer::BearerAuth`

as

`bearer::BearerAuth`

and

`actix_web_httpauth::headers::www_authenticate::bearer::Error`

as

`bearer::Error`

It is not possible, because it would require these two statements, which conflict:

```
use actix_web_httpauth::extractors::bearer;
use actix_web_httpauth::headers::www_authenticate::bearer;
```

Admittedly, this is an edge case, but it does seem odd to me that it is not possible to specify a subset of a namespace while still retaining a partial path to that namespace.

The most reasonable solution seems to be something like:

```
use actix_web_httpauth::extractors::bearer as xbearer;
use actix_web_httpauth::headers::www_authenticate::bearer as ybearer;

...

xbearer::BearerAuth ...
ybearer::Error ...
```